# reorder divs in more rows on small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am in the process of creating a responsive design for my table lookalike elements. On the wide screens, I have 2x3 elements (2 rows, 3 columns) with the max-width of 1200px. When the screen width is between 800px and 1200px, I wanted to transform the "table" into 3x2 (3 rows, 2 columns) and at widths below 800px, there should be just one column of 6 rows. The following code correctly displays 2x3 elements at widths beyond 1200px, but it fails to transform when the screen size is lower.

Basically, the question is, what should I put in media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}
```

This is a link to [my work so far](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBbLPK). SO "Run code" kinda messes things up, because of its small width.

What would the best approach to handle this scenario?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper-1 {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.wrapper-3 {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.left-side {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.left-side > .image {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat center center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.right-side {
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100px;
}
.right-side > .title {
  margin: 0;
}
.element-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.element {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="element-container">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="element-container">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
          <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
          <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you already start with flex in container element, you should use it also in block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a variety of ways.

- Float your items and change the item width on different media queries, so that the sum of the item's widths results in two, three, *n* columns.
- Use flexbox, and again change the item's width to until you get the desired column number.
- Use native CSS columns

You need to simplify your markup. What you want is something along the lines of:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="image">…</div>
      <div class="text">…</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">…</div>
  <div class="grid-item">…</div>
  <div class="grid-item">…</div>
</div>
```

If you group your markup into rows you are going to run into obvious problems.

Answer (score 0):

if can change rows and columns than your html is incorrect
element-container is main and all wrapper-1 div set into 1 element-container

**Use at media between 1200px - 800px use**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper-1{
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
  }
}
```

**use this when screen size smaller then 800px**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .wrapper-1{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element-container">
<div class="element">
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-1">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
        <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star You are a rock star</p>
      </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

i hope this one is helping u